# Indexing an answer limited to after today in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to put together a company excel sheet to keep track of the tickets we give out to senior sales to take out clients.

I put together a "Soonest Available Ticket" section to easily ID what games are coming up we still have tickets for. However, we don't give out tickets to every game and so I want to have these formulas return dates only of games that have not happened yet. Right now, they simply return the first unclaimed game which are all in the past.

I've tinkered with a few formulas, but I can't figure out how to only command it to look at dates today or later. Any ideas?

Below, in order, are my original Index formula, and then my attempts to only find upcoming games.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CubsDate,MATCH("Avail*",CubsTicketStatus,0),1),"Filled")
=IF(WhiteSoxDate>NOW(),IFERROR(INDEX(WhiteSoxDate,MATCH("Avail*",WhiteSoxTicketStatus,0),1),"Filled"),"Season Ended")
=IF(WhiteSoxDate>NOW(),INDEX(WhiteSoxDate,MATCH("Avail*",WhiteSoxTicketStatus,0),1),"Season Ended")
{=INDEX(WhiteSoxDate,(MATCH("Av*"&"*">TODAY(),WhiteSoxTicketStatus&WhiteSoxDate,0)))}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "*CubsDate*" and "*CubsTicketStatus*" are named ranges of cells (the former containing dates and the latter the status, either "*Avail*" or "*Filled*"), then perhaps this will do what you want:

```
{=INDEX(CubsDate,MATCH(1,(CubsTicketStatus="Avail")*(CubsDate>TODAY()),0))}
```

Note that if there is no matching date after the current date, you'll get an `#N/A` result (which you could easily test for).

Here's a test I ran:

[image]

Note that the data here is in rows 25 - 31.  Also, you'll need to format the result as a date.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Here's an explanation of how the Match function is being used.  (I edited the answer so that future generations will find it more easily than if I added a comment.)

As a reminder (because I'm old and forgetful), the Match function takes three parms:  `Lookup Value`, `Lookup Array`, and `Match Type`.  So in

```
MATCH(1,(CubsTicketStatus="Avail")*(CubsDate>TODAY()),0)
```

we're looking for a value of 1 with a match type of 0 (exact match).  That's the easy part.  Our `Lookup Array`, however, is a little more complex.  It consists of two tests multiplied by each other.  So in each row, it looks at the value in CubsTicketStatus to see if it is "Avail" and it looks at the value in CubsDate to see if it's after today.

Each of those tests results in either `TRUE` or `FALSE` but, when you put them in the context of a mathematical calculation, they are `1` and `0`.  So if they're both `TRUE`, then you get 1 * 1, but if either (or both) is `FALSE`, you get zero.  The Match function then returns the first row where both are `TRUE` -- that is, the first row where tickets are "Avail" and the date is after `TODAY()`.

Comment: I ended up changing the TicketStatus columns to say 'past' when the date was more than today, but your answer is much more inline with what I had originally been going for.  Do you mind breaking down how the syntax you have in `match` works? I've never seen it use * before.

Comment: I added an explanation which is probably as clear as mud.  8^)  Let me know if you have any more questions.